# Nginx redirect all POST traffic to another server

Tags: nginx, apache2, url-rewriting, centos6

I am in the middle of setting up a 3 node web server cluster running Nginx , Apache 2 and MySQL.

The question is this.  In my rewrite rules on web server 2 - 3 I want to direct all POST traffic to Web Server 1 ( on the private network if possible).  All servers are behind a load balancer.

So what would I need to put in the conf file for the vhost to redirect all traffic to Web server 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ($request_method = POST) {
  proxy_pass http://server1;
}
```